# Как найти на каком диске RAID 10 лежит конкретный файл?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, raid

Есть софтраид RAID 10 (Ubuntu 16.04), на нем большие файлы. Стал замечать что эпизодически скачиваемый оттуда файл оказывается битый. Я сравнивал контрольные суммы md5sum одного и того же файла и они менялись и их всегда было две. Я подозреваю, что на одном из дисков зеркала лежит битый файл, либо глючит контроллер, через который этот конкретный диск подключен. Я знаю контрольную сумма битого файла. Как узнать на каком из дисков этот файл? mdadm бэдов не видит.

Comment: Ну а смарты чё говорят хотя бы?

Comment: Специально проверил все диски раида, все по 0/0/0 errors

Comment: Ну если есть свободный винт и бэкапы рейда делаются - я бы попробовал этот винт вставлять на место 1, потом второго и так далее, зануляя между итерациями. Да, небыстро, да, небезопасно, но лично у меня нет других идей.